# Прочитать из файла и записать в односвязный список

Tags: c

Здравствуйте нужно прочитать из файла и записать в односвязный список

Вот моя структура:

```
struct prog {
char name[80];
unsigned int kol;
double time1;
double time2;

struct prog* next;
};
```

Вот мой код который не работает(

```
struct prog* zad8(void) {

struct prog* head = NULL;
prog* p = NULL,*pred=NULL;
FILE* g;
fopen_s(&g, "fileG.txt", "r");
head = pred = p = (prog*)malloc(sizeof(prog));
while (fscanf(g, "%-18s%-22u%-32.2lf%-28.2lf\n", p->name, &p->kol, &p->time1, &p->time2) != EOF) {
    p = (prog*)malloc(sizeof(prog));
    pred->next = p;
    pred = p;
}
p->next = NULL;

return head;
}
```

вот что находится в моем файле 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я бы попробовал вот такой формат `" |%s |%d |%lf |%lf | "` (с пробелом в начале и конце) и может быть заменил во входных данных `,` на `.` (тут зависит от конкретной локали)

Comment: Я не вижу как вы определяете `locale`. В виндовской может быть у числах точка это запятая (**,**), а в Си точка (**.**). Может быть вы записываете и считываете в разных локалях. Как всегда очень мало информации вы выкладываете, как пишите, как читаете...

Comment: Duplicate https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1100804/%d0%97%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b2%d1%8f%d0%b7%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0