# Заполнить односвязный список с файла

Tags: c

Здравствуйте нужно заполнить односвязный список из файла

Моя структура:

```
struct prog {
char name[80];
unsigned int kol;
double time1;
double time2;

struct prog* next;
};
```

Мой неудачный код:

```
struct prog* zad8(void) {

struct prog* head = NULL;

prog* p = NULL, * pred = NULL;
FILE* g;
head = pred = p;
fopen_s(&g, "fileG.txt", "r");
while (fscanf(g, "%s\n%u\n%lf\n%lf\n",p->name , &p->kol, &p->time1, &p->time2) != EOF) {
    p = (prog*)malloc(sizeof(prog));
    pred->next = p;
    pred = p;
}

return head;
}
```

в файле информация находится так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вначале надо выделять ресурс, потом его использовать. А вообще, научитесь вопросы задавать -- не мы же должны гадать на кофейной гуще, что у вас там болит.

Comment: Можете посмотреть мои примеры (правда двусвязный список, но это не имеет большого значения): https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy, https://pastebin.com/TwN3SiCd (в обоих случаях смотри имплементацию `prepare()`)